# Find items of a certain class (a) that are also in other classes (b,c,d)

Tags: javascript, jquery

A bit hard to explain, but here it goes.

I've got a class, .possibleMatch.

I've also got an array, myPicks, with a list of other classes (.silver, .music, .newest).

There is an unordered list, and each li has been assigned certain classes (.possibleMatch, .silver, .music, .gold, .newest, .platinum)

Now what I'm trying to do is find every item in class .possibleMatch from the ul, that is also in classes from myPicks, so .silver, .music and .newest, and update .possibleMatch with only those items.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<myPicks.length; i++) {

    $('.possibleMatch').has(myPicks[i]);
}
```

and

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<myPicks.length; i++) {
    $('.possibleMatch').hasClass(myPicks[i]);
}
```

and

```
var i;
for(i=0; i<myPicks.length; i++) {

    $('.possibleMatch').filter(myPicks[i]);
}
```

The array, myPicks, is filled with the *names in strings* of the classes, not the actual classes themselves. Is this the problem when I pair it with filter, has, and hasClass?

The array is updated when a button is clicked, each with the classname:

```
var myPicks[];
$('.button').click( function() {
    var hello = " " + $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    myPicks.push(hello);
}
```

Thanks, and my apologies if it's hard to understand!

--
Edit: Here's the HTML

```
<ul id="trueMatch">
        <li class="possibleMatch silver music newest" id="uno">VW</li>
        <li class="possibleMatch platinum music" id="dos"> AC </li>
        <li class="possibleMatch gold music newest" id="tres"> ML</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: to which element the class `possibleMatch` is assigned? can you share a sample html

Comment: There's no need to store this data in the DOM and read it back. That's what data structures like arrays and objects are for.

Comment: Why are you adding a space before each class name in myPicks?

Comment: @ArunPJohny possibleMatch is assigned to an <li> item

Comment: @Stan see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

what you can try is

if the `possibleMatch` class is assigned to `li`s along with `myPicks` class like `<li class="possibleMatch silver">ddd</li>` then

```
var $lis = $('.possibleMatch').filter(myPicks.join(','));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7XSQe/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Two questions: 1. Is $lis still a class? 2. I'm not quite sure if the part where I'm assigning classes to myPicks is correct - I think they may be missing the "." before the class name. Is there a way to get around that?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$('.possibleMatch').each(function() {
    var elment = $(this);
    for( var i=0; i<myPicks.length; i++){
        if ( elment.hasClass( myPicks[i] ) {

        }
    }
});
```

Assuming that array contains class names without the dot